# How to test global middlware in expressJS?

Tags: express, unit-testing, nestjs, middleware

This seems like a simple question, but I'm stumped. How do I test my expressjs middleware is setting up the user session properly?

```
app.use((req:Req, res:Response, next:NextFunction) => {
  req.userSessionId = uuid();
  next();
});
```

I am not sure how to test that an incoming request is being captured and setting the userSessionId correctly. I want something like

```
describe('setting up middleware', ()=> {
 //instantiate the app
 expect(app.use).tobeCalled();
 expect(mockReq).toBeSetWith(userSessionId)

});
```

Comment: You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest

Comment: @LinDu Is there a way of testing this without adding another package to my project?

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor your middleware code into a function, and write unit-tests that test this function logic.

Your unit tests, in my opinion ([and others](https://plainenglish.io/blog/how-to-unit-test-express-middleware-typescript-jest-c6a7ad166e74)), should only test **your** code and **avoid** testing Express logic (calling your middleware). For this you should have integration tests which test your app is working properly as a whole

```
// This middleware code needs to be tested
const userSessionMiddleare = (req: Request, res:Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  req.userSessionId = uuid();
  next();
};

// This Express logic should not be unit-tested but rather tested in your integration testing
app.use(userSessionMiddleare);
```